# django subtracting one query from another

Tags: python, django

I have two identical models in django

```
class Car(models.Model):
brand = models.ForeignKey(
    'Brand',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    verbose_name="ID бренда")
car_name = models.TextField(verbose_name="Авто")
year = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Год")
price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Цена")
power = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Мощность двигателя")
engine_type = models.TextField(verbose_name="Тип двигателя")
drive = models.TextField(verbose_name="Привод")
transmission = models.TextField(verbose_name="КПП")
mileage = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Пробег")
city = models.TextField(verbose_name="Город")
photo = models.URLField(verbose_name="Фото")
url = models.URLField(verbose_name="Ссылка")
vin = models.TextField(verbose_name="VIN")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Машина"
    verbose_name_plural = "Машины"

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.brand}'
```

and the same table

Don't mind the Russian names, I couldn't find the answer in Russian

```
new_cars_values.union(old_cars_values)
```

I need to find the differences between the two tables, find what was added and what was removed. The first table stores old machine data, the second stores new machine data. To get the deleted machines I have to subtract the first from the second and the new machines from the first from the second. I tried using .union, but I have asynchronous parser and it always gives me different values and I can't compare the lists because they are always different. How to compare data in two tables regardless of their indexes?

Comment: Is the `Id` the same on both tables, or you should to compare by all fields? Do you need to make the query on database, or is it right to do it in memory?

Comment: I need to compare all the fields and find out if there is a difference, and if there is, I need to save it in a separate table

Comment: You can compose a hash from all fields and compare hashes instead field by field.